# Formatting .py file using HTML

Tags: python, html, terminal

I want to format a .py file (that generates a random face every time the page is refreshed) using HTML, in the Terminal, that can run in a browser. I have **chmod`ed** it so it should work, but whenever I run in it in a browser, I get an **internal service error**. Can someone help me figure out what it wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print ""

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<pre>

from random import choice

def facegenerator():
  T = ""
  hair = ["I I I I I","^ ^ ^ ^ ^"]
  eyes = ["O   O"," O O ",]
  nose = ["  O  ","  v  "]
  mouth = ["~~~~~","_____","-----"]
  T += choice(hair)
  T += "\n"
  T += choice(eyes)
  T += "\n"
  T += choice(nose)
  T += "\n"
  T += choice(mouth)
  T += "\n"
  return T

print facegenerator()
</pre>
</html>
```

The code works in IDLE, but I can`t it to work on a webpage. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither valid HTML nor valid Python. You can't simply mix in HTML tags into the middle of a Python script like that: you need at the very least to put them inside quotes so that they are a valid string.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print """

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<pre>
"""
def ...

print facegenerator()
print """</pre>
</html>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a templating engine like jinja to have this http://jinja.pocoo.org/